React router dom does not load components
I have to build a web application, where questions are asked and based on what you are answering you are getting to the next place id.
When I click to start the game, I get to the first ID, which ist perfect. But when I then click on a possible answer, the ort?id changes from 1 to 2 in the URL, but the new question does not load. Only when I manually reboot the site, the new question will show up.
I'm not really experienced with JS, but here are my to .jsx files which I think are important for my question.
Thanks already for your help.:)
App.jsx
import React from "react";
import Startseite from "./components/Startseite";
import Spiel from "./components/Spiel";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Startseite />} />
        <Route path="/ort?id" element={<Spiel />} /> 
        <Route path="/ort" element={<Startseite />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;

Spiel.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

function Spiel() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [ort, setOrt] = useState(null);
  const [umfrage, setUmfrage] = useState(null);
  const [antworten, setAntworten] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect wird ausgeführt mit location.key:", location.key);
    const ladeOrt = async () => {
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      const qrId = searchParams.get("id");
      if (qrId) {
        try {
          // State-Variablen zurücksetzen
          setOrt(null);
          setUmfrage(null);
          setAntworten([]);

          const response = await fetch(`/api/ort/${qrId}`);
          const data = await response.json();
          setOrt(data.ort);
          setUmfrage(data.umfragen[0]);
          setAntworten(data.antworten);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Fehler beim Laden der Daten:", error);
        }
      }
    };
    ladeOrt();
  }, [location.key]);

  return (
    <div>
      {ort && (
        <div>
          <h2>{ort.name}</h2>
          {umfrage && antworten.length > 0 && (
            <div>
              <p>{umfrage.frage}</p>
              <ul>
                {antworten.map((antwort) => (
                  <li key={antwort.id}>
                    <Link to={`/ort?id=${antwort.ziel_ort_id}`}>
                      {antwort.antwort}
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}
          <MapContainer center={[53.1437, 8.2137]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: "400px" }}>
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {ort && (
              <Marker position={[ort.lat, ort.long]}>
                <Popup>
                  {ort.name}
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
            )}
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Spiel;

I tried fixing it with Gemini, but he tried to fix the App.jsx, which only made it worse lol.

"/ort?id" isn't a valid route path value, it can't be matched. The route paths should include any search params.
You are already rendering Startseite on "/", so assuming you trying to navigate to "/ort" with some id search string value and want Spiel to then render, I suggest the following:

Remove the path="/ort?id" route.
Render Spiel on the path="ort" route.

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Startseite />} />
        <Route path="/ort" element={<Spiel />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}


Use the useSearchParams hook in Spiel to read the current id search string value.
Use the qrId value as the useEffect hook dependency to trigger the effect only when the id search parameter value chnages.

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
...

function Spiel() {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const [ort, setOrt] = useState(null);
  const [umfrage, setUmfrage] = useState(null);
  const [antworten, setAntworten] = useState([]);

  const qrId = searchParams.get("id");

  useEffect(() => {
    const ladeOrt = async () => {
      try {
        // State-Variablen zurücksetzen
        setOrt(null);
        setUmfrage(null);
        setAntworten([]);

        const response = await fetch(`/api/ort/${qrId}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setOrt(data.ort);
        setUmfrage(data.umfragen[0]);
        setAntworten(data.antworten);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Fehler beim Laden der Daten:", error);
      }
    };

    if (qrId) {
      ladeOrt();
    }
  }, [qrId]);

  return (
    <div>
      {ort && (
        <div>
          <h2>{ort.name}</h2>
          {umfrage && antworten.length > 0 && (
            <div>
              <p>{umfrage.frage}</p>
              <ul>
                {antworten.map((antwort) => (
                  <li key={antwort.id}>
                    <Link to={`/ort?id=${antwort.ziel_ort_id}`}>
                      {antwort.antwort}
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          )}
          ...
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

